# How to get first line of a tuple and the third item in its tuple. Need Help, Anybody?

Tags: python

I have these values which I store in a:

```
a = (1.425, 4.82145395112958, 0.0656498375731458)
    (1.39716316090366, 7.2, 0.102480129941483)
    (7.425, 4.82145395112958, 0.0656498375731458)
    (7.39716316090366, 7.2, 0.102480129941483)
    (7.425, -0.928546048870416, 0.0656498375731458)
    (7.39716316090366, 0.95, 0.102480129941483)
    (1.425, -0.928546048870416, 0.0656498375731458)
    (1.39716316090366, 0.95, 0.102480129941483)

print a[2]
```

Output:

```
0.0656498375731458
0.102480129941483
0.0656498375731458
0.102480129941483
0.0656498375731458
0.102480129941483
0.0656498375731458
0.102480129941483
```

I tried this also:

```
print a[0][2]
```

with this :

```
print a[0][2]
```

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Py\check cartesian.py", line 26, in <module>
print a[0][2]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I only need this first single value to print:

```
0.0656498375731458
```

Comment: Are you sure that a looks exactly how you write? If a is a tuple of tuples then you are missing `(` at the beginning ant `)` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the tuple without main parenthesis, this works:

```
a = ((1.425, 4.82145395112958, 0.0656498375731458, ), 
    (1.39716316090366, 7.2, 0.102480129941483, ), 
    (7.425, 4.82145395112958, 0.0656498375731458, ), 
    (7.39716316090366, 7.2, 0.102480129941483, ), 
    (7.425, -0.928546048870416, 0.0656498375731458, ), 
    (7.39716316090366, 0.95, 0.102480129941483, ), 
    (1.425, -0.928546048870416, 0.0656498375731458, ), 
    (1.39716316090366, 0.95, 0.102480129941483, ), )

print(a[0][2])
```

Comment: I didn't write this tuple, I got them from my file, those are the exact coordinates I got.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try using a list**

```
a = [(1.425, 4.82145395112958, 0.0656498375731458), 
    (1.39716316090366, 7.2, 0.102480129941483), 
    (7.425, 4.82145395112958, 0.0656498375731458), 
    (7.39716316090366, 7.2, 0.102480129941483), 
    (7.425, -0.928546048870416, 0.0656498375731458), 
    (7.39716316090366, 0.95, 0.102480129941483), 
    (1.425, -0.928546048870416, 0.0656498375731458 ), 
    (1.39716316090366, 0.95, 0.102480129941483), ]
print(a[0][2])
```

Comment: how to make a list?
I'm very new to python.